# ajax call executes without ajax complete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am calling a file with ajax.
The ajax call works fine when I remove ajaxcomplete code line.
But the data that prints is not satisfactory.
How do I find what is making my ajaxcomplete, incomplete..
Help me figure out this.

Thank you.

What is that I need to do here? Thanks..

When I use the script below,I get the response in firebug, but it is not displaying.

ajax script

```
$("#form1").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        plid: "required",
    },
    messages: {
        plid: "Please select a pack name id..",
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        loading_show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load_data.php",
            data: $('#form1').serialize() + "&page=1",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#container").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                    loading_hide();
                    $("#container").html(msg);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no reason for you to use ajaxComplete in the success handler, the ajax is already complete.

Comment: @KevinB  ok. thanks for the info. But any idea why this would be incomplete?

Comment: it IS complete. you don't need to wait for it to be complete!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.8, the [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) method should only be attached to `document`.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
    // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `success` in your Ajax object, there's no need to use `.ajaxComplete()`. Just take it out:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load_data.php",
    data: $('#form1').serialize() + "&page=1",
    success: function(msg) {
        loading_hide();
        $("#container").html(msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below for accomplishing the task.

`$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
              loading_hide();
          });`

or you can use ajax start and stop.

`$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
              loading_show();
          });
          $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
              loading_hide();
          });`